# MVVM Saving changes to viewmodel using a command confusion

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

I have a `GridView` displaying an `ObservableCollection<Models>`. When I select an item, the `TextBoxe`s get populated to allow for editing and adding new `Model`s. However, when I edit the textboxes, the gridview and the ViewModel automatically get updated with the revisions. I am trying to use a button command to save/cancel revisions instead.

I've included my **View** and my **ViewModel**. I'm still relatively new at this, and I have been following this tutorial http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798384.aspx, and I'm not sure what I can change in order to make it work the way I want.

When I go to create a NewModel, SelectedModel changes with NewModel as well. So Confused!

My View:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Models}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedModel}" 
          IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Models" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding ModelName}">
            <GridViewColumn Header="Template" 
                            DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Template.TemplateID}">
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
    <TextBox DataContext="{Binding SelectedModel}" Text="{Binding ModelName, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <TextBox DataContext="{Binding SelectedModel}" Text="{Binding TemplateID, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    <Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveModelCommand}" />
    <Button Content="Cancel" Command="{Binding CancelModelCommand}" />
    <Button Content="Add Model" Command="{Binding AddModelCommand}" />
```

My ViewModel:

```
private Model _selectedModel = null;
private Model _newModel = null;
private RelayCommand _addmodelcommand;
private RelayCommand _editmodelcommand;
private RelayCommand _savemodelcommand;

public Model SelectedModel
{
    get { return _selectedModel; }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedModel != value)
        {
            _selectedModel = value; RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedModel");
        }
    }
}

public Model NewModel
{
    get { return _newModel; }
    set 
    {
       _newModel = value;
       RaisePropertyChanged("NewModel");
    }
}

public RelayCommand AddModelCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_addmodelcommand == null)
        {
           _addmodelcommand = new RelayCommand(p => SetNewModel(),
                                               p => true);
        }
        return _addmodelcommand;
    }
    set 
    { 
        _addmodelcommand = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("AddModel");
    }
}

public RelayCommand SaveModelCommand
{
    get
    {
        if (_savemodelcommand == null)
        {
            _savemodelcommand = new RelayCommand(p => ModelSaved(), 
                                                 p => true);
        }
        return _savemodelcommand;
    }
    set
    {
        _savemodelcommand = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("SaveModel");
    }
}

public void SetNewModel()
{
    if (NewModel == null)
    { 
       NewModel = new Model();
    }
    else
    {
       NewModel.ModelName = string.Empty; 
    }
    SelectedModel = NewModel;
}

public string ModelSaved()
{
    string error = null;
    if (error == null)
    {
        if (SelectedModel != NewModel)
        {
            UpdateModel(SelectedModel);
        }
        else //adds new model
        {
          //Add the new model to the data context.
          _ESTContext.Models.Add(NewModel);

          //Add the new model to the observable collection.
          this.Models.Add(NewModel);

          this.SelectedModel = NewModel;
          NewModel = null;
        }
        _ESTContext.SaveChanges();
    }
    return error;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to notify about changes on properties that never change. That includes properties returning commands, you can just lazily initialize them, setters are redundant.

Comment: `ListView` is deprecated, instead use a `DataGrid` with `CanUserAddRows="True"` and it should do the job with minimal development.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you are using EntityFramework which is designed to track your changes and only save them when you call `_ESTContext.SaveChanges()`. So I would change the way you are approaching this.

Currently it seems like you want to make the user click save or cancel before moving on to another item in your ListView. I propose that you let the user click on an item, modify it using your text boxes, click on another item if they want and modify that one. The user can also click the add button as many times as they want. Then when they are done with ALL of their changes then clicking the Save button should simply do any error checking on all of the data (if you want) and then call `_ESTContext.SaveChanges()`. That will save all of the changes at once. Similarly make the cancel button a global cancel button which can be implemented as simply as doing `_ESTContext = new WhateverContext();` and then refreshing your `Models` property.

This approach also allows the user to click the save button whenever they want so they can in theory still save after every modification if they really wanted to.

Comment: Hmmm. I see.  I noticed that, but what if I want to allow the user to edit/add one at a time? Could I just create a new Model Object in the viewmodel, and insert that into the main viewmodel when "save" is clicked?

Comment: That would work only for new Models though because you would have to bind your textboxes to an `AddedModel` property. What is wrong with doing that? Well then how are you going to modify already existing `Model`? You would have to have two sets of textboxes because you can only have one binding per textbox. Based on your comment you would most benefit from using a DataGrid instead of your ListView. Check out this super simple tutorial on datagrids: http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/datagrid-control/introduction/ That is part one of 3. Parts 2 and 3 will be of most use to you.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your insight. Appreciate it. I'm thinking of just opening a dialog, passing the values to and from. I'll try that out and if not possible, I guess i'll just have to stick with that you suggested.